Powershell Argument was missing the terminator: "

I am having problem with powershell arg design like this
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& { $scriptContent = Get-Content -Path 'C:\path\to\your\script.ps1' -Raw; $command = \"`$scriptContent -key 'BlRznMbcP5azbwi4' -filePath 'C:\path\to\your\file.txt'\"; Invoke-Expression $command }"

And I got some errors like
The string is missing the terminator: ".
+ CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Because using powershell type them on screen I don't like to use that way. But they work with command
$scriptContent = Get-Content -Path '{0}' -Raw; Invoke-Expression \"& {{ $scriptContent }} -key 'BlRznMbcP5azbwi4' -filePath '{1}'\"

executed on my .net application.
I need someone to correct my argument

As an aside: There's no reason to use "& { ... }" in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the -Command (-c) parameter - just use "..." directly. Older versions of the CLI documentation erroneously suggested that & { ... } is required, but this has since been corrected.



Your PowerShell CLI (powershell.exe) command line is designed to be executed from outside PowerShell (except for the ` before $, which is only needed and appropriate inside PowerShell), such as from cmd.exe or via direct, shell-free execution such as via the System.Diagnostics.Process .NET API.

In such contexts, the " characters embedded inside your overall "..." -Command argument require escaping as \", as in  your command (and not `" or "", as would be required when calling from PowerShell).


From inside Windows PowerShell, you need additional escaping, unfortunately, to also satisfy PowerShell's string-literal syntax: \`" or \"" - neglecting to do so results in the error message you saw.

This double escaping shouldn't be necessary, however, and indeed no longer is in v7.3+ of PowerShell (Core) 7 (whose CLI is pwsh.exe) - see this answer for background information; in short: the necessary \-escaping now happens automatically, behind the scenes.

Because of this, and because additional syntactic modifications to a cmd.exe / no-shell command line may be required when calling from PowerShell, it is preferable to pass the command to execute as a script block, where you only need to satisfy PowerShell's syntax; e.g., powershell.exe { "Nat `"King`" Cole" }
However, note that this technique works only from PowerShell.
More fundamentally, calling the PowerShell CLI from PowerShell is rarely needed (only needed if you need process isolation), and calling it requires creation of a PowerShell child process whose startup cost is significant.





Your specific command can be greatly simplified, which also bypasses the escaping requirements, and results in a command line that works from both cmd.exe / no-shell invocations and from inside PowerShell:
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\path\to\your\script.ps1" -key "BlRznMbcP5azbwi4" -filePath "C:\path\to\your\file.txt"

Note the use of the -File parameter to pass the target script path, followed by the pass-through arguments, and how all arguments are enclosed in "..." ('...' wouldn't work with -File from outside PowerShell).
